# Chapter 2 Corollary 2.7 of Colding and Minicozzi's minimal surfaces book

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I have a question about the last step in the proof of corollary 2.7 in the chapter 2 of Colding and Minicozzi's book *A Course in Minimal Surfaces*.

**Corollary 2.7** If $\Sigma^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is immersed and minimal, $B_{r_0}^{\Sigma}\subset \Sigma^2$ is an intrinsic disk of radius $r_0$, and $B_{r_0}^{\Sigma}\cap\partial\Sigma=\emptyset$, then
$$something=2(Area(B_{r_0}^{\Sigma})-\pi r_0^2)\le Length(\partial B_{r_0}^{\Sigma})-2\pi r_0^2.$$

The proof of this last inequality is first to notice that $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}Length(\partial B_t^{\Sigma})\ge 0$$ by a previous lemma, therefore
$$t\frac{d}{dt}Length(\partial B_t^{\Sigma})\ge Length(\partial B_t^{\Sigma})$$

therefore

$$\frac{d}{dt}(Length(\partial B_t^{\Sigma})/t)\ge 0.$$

The authors say that the inequality that we want now follows easily. However, I cannot see why. Intuitively the length of $\partial B_t^{\Sigma}$ should be $c(t)\pi t$ and we now know $c(t)$ is increasing.

I guess then we should use the coarea formula somehow to finish it, but I just cannot write it out explicitly. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I integrated the equation:

$\int_0^{r_0} t\frac{d}{dt}Length(\partial B_t^\Sigma)\geq \int_0^{r_0}Length(\partial B_t^\Sigma)$

Observed that right hand side is equal to $Area(B_{r_0}^\Sigma)$

By integrating by parts left hand side we get:

$r_0Length(\partial B_t^\Sigma)- Area(B_{r_0}^\Sigma)\geq Area(B_{r_0}^\Sigma)$

and hence we conclude by subtracting from both equations $2\pi r_0^2$